# How to count the buttons clicks, with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem with google analytics code when i try to count how many times, clicked a specific button, on my wordpress site. To be more specific, on my website, i would like to count, with google analytics, how many times someones click specifics buttons. 
So the steps i followed for doing this were:

1. inserted this code:
   [image]

inside of buttons tags, which i would like to count.

2. Created a goal event in google analytics, which in "goal details" in analytics, i inserted these values
   for "Category"-Form
   for "Action"-Button
   for "Label"-Business Strategy.
   When i saved both of them, in the beginning, google analytics counted how many times click the specific button, but after a while stopped the count.

I would like to ask, i had made anything wrong with the code and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not a picture of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how many times the button has been clicked from the report '**Behavior -> Events -> Top Events**' under column '**Total events**'.

The goal instead counts the sessions that triggered that event, so if an user in a session clicks 5 times on the button you will get 5 total events but only one goal (also intended as a unique event).